# how do I rename part of a variable in python using another variable

Tags: python-2.7

I have a configuration file which defines a variable

```
project = "ORB"
```

using this , I want to rename variable(s) in my code

```
project_unique_tags
```

to

```
ORB_unique_tags
```

notice how only the bold portion in the variable **project**_unique_tags is to be replaced with the value "ORB" (without the quotes ofcourse)

how to achieve this?

Comment: You [don't](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.cl/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Comment: edited my question to further clarify

Comment: I think the end of your clarification got cut off ...

Comment: thanks @ZeroPiraeus. edited.

Comment: It doesn't matter that you only want to create *some* of the variable name dynamically. The question is functionally identical, and the answer is still: **don't**. Again, read the linked article for why.

Comment: ... and, I'm dropping out of the conversation now. You've got a clear pointer that you should be able to understand.

Comment: all I want to do is make the variables more generic by providing a user the ability to specify the project name the script is being run for in a configuration file. Then in my code, I create variables with the names as specified in the configuration file.

Comment: @Imran: why would you need to do that? Programs don't normally adjust their variable names for each project or document or image they are run for. Why should the user care about what variables the program uses in the first place?